# No more suggestions in XML

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, gradle

I'm not getting autofill suggestions anymore in my XML files. I'm not sure what I did. I think it has to do something with my Gradle file but unable to pinpoint. As I understand it, the "*xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools*" is where that comes from. I think the problem could be that I am using material buttons and app compat or something like that. I have resynced the Gradle multiple times as well. Usually, I could type something in like "wi" and it would show a drop-down menu with a bunch of suggestions. Can anyone spot the problem?

Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.firetest"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.lorentzos.swipecards:library:1.0.9'
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    //implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.1.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha06'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'


}
```

Example XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="100"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".SignUpProcess.PhotoActivity.Photo_Activity">

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="20">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="204dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_black"
            android:text="Add your photos here"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
            android:textSize="32dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_black"
            android:text="Please add at least three photos"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="12dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout

        android:id="@+id/rl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="66"
        tools:context=".SignUpProcess.PhotoActivity.Photo_Activity">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipToPadding="false">

        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/continueBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="223dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/next_btn" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="14dp">

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try Invalidate caches and restart under File menu in Android Studio.

Comment: @Nicolas Tried several times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to check `power mode` in the android studio. 
Go to `File > Power mode` and check its's on or off. If it is on, You also will not get any suggestions.

**Update:** If it doesn't work for you then you should reset your Android studio which will set the default configuration for you. For that, find out `.AndroidStudioBeta` or `.AndroidStudio` folder and delete those and restart android studio. Generally, you will get this folder into `users\[user name]\`.

Let me know if it helps you then. 
Happy coding..!

Comment: Deleting that folder(s) solved the issue. Not sure why though. Thanks!

Comment: So, `.AndroidStudio` or `.AndroiStudioBeta` file contains all configurations and settings. If you delete that and restart the android studio. That will configure every setting again and you will get default setting, It is kind of reset Android studio. Most of the issues regarding setting and configuration have solved for me by this trick. 
Btw, Happy to help you. Thanks for accepting the answer. :)